# focusout and click event execution order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have defined a `focusout` event handler on a text box and a `click` handler on a button. If I focus inside the text input and then directly click the button, then both the events get fired, as expected. `focusout` event gets fired first and `click` is fired if developer toolbar is opened else its fires in vice-versa manner.

What could be actual reason behind this?

Here is the snippet for the ones asking, but I believe question itself was clear enough:

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('blur', function(){ alert("Input Focused Out"); });
        document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){ alert("Button Clicked"); });
```

```html
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" />
<button id="myButton" name="myButton" >Button</button>
```

Comment: "in vice-versa manner" mean what exactly?

Comment: can you provide a small demo of what your actual situation?

Answer (score 9):

I think, when you are comparing order of click event and blur event, **blur should always trigger before click** event irrespective of debugger tool.
The reason being click involves mousedown+mouseup. It means, **until mouse button is released, click event will not get triggered**.

I tested in a fiddle and found that if we find such a case, we should use mousedown event instead of click event.
As I tested more, I found that order of mousedown is always before blur event so in such a case, **mousedown will trigger first and then blur event will trigger**.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3gyq93a/1/

JS:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('blur', function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "blur"; 
});
        document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "mousedown";
});

 document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "click";
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" />
<button id="myButton" name="myButton" >Button</button>


<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```